# how can we access form2 listbox (lb1) in form3

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Imports System.Windows.Forms.ListBox

Public Class Form2

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)    Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim mf1 As New Form3()
    Form3.Visible = True
    Me.Hide()

End Sub
```

Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form3

```
Private Class dataaccess
    Public Shared Function getconnection() As OleDbConnection
        'string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\database\Database2007.accdb";
        Dim constr1 As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Suman\Desktop\vs ws\vb\project_sample1\Database1.accdb"
        Return New OleDbConnection(constr1)
    End Function
End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = dataaccess.getconnection()
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM Burgers"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    ' Dim x As Integer
    da.Fill(ds)

    **lb1**.Items.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).ItemArray(0).ToString())

End Sub
```

I want to store the form 3 data into lb1 listbox which is declared in the form 2

Comment: does your both forms active at a time ?

Comment: What is the VBScript part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a reference to that specific listbox or the entire form2 to form3. the easy way is to write it into the constructor of the form.

In Form3:

```
private _TargetListBox as ListBox

public sub New(ByRef TargetListBox as ListBox)
    _TargetListBox = TargetListBox
end sub 


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = dataaccess.getconnection()
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM Burgers"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    ' Dim x As Integer
    da.Fill(ds)
    _TargetListBox.Items.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).ItemArray(0).ToString())
End Sub
```

In Form2:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim mf1 As New Form3(Me.lb1)
    mf1.Visible = True
    Me.Hide()
```

End Sub

Comment: can u show it by writing code,am unable to create the instance of form 2 @zohar peled

Comment: Still,it is throwing an error stating to create a method stub @ zohar peled

Comment: What exactly is the exception and on what code line do you get it?

Comment: in the Form2,second line,i am getting this error "lb1 is not a member of 'project_sample1.Form2' " @zohar peled

Comment: well, you are the one that said it's a listbox on form2...
maybe it's called by a different name?
Me.lb1 in the code I wrote is referring to the list box on form2.
if the listbox is not named lb1, you should change that to it's real name.

Comment: i wanted to use form 2 listbox(lb1) in form3 @zohar peled

Comment: yes, but the exception you are getting says that you don't have a member called lb1 in Form2. What is the listbox name? (you can switch to design mode, click on the listbox, press the f4 key and see it's name in the properties window.)

Comment: I am able to execute it,but it is showing blank window,when compiler encounters Dim mf1 As New Form3(me._Targetlistbox) @zohar peled

Comment: I'm sorry, wtf? _TargetListbox is in Form3, not Form2.
Did you read my previous comment?

Comment: iam trying to figure the mistake..thanks for the help@zohar peled